# How to expect throw with Mocha and Chai?

Tags: javascript, mocha.js, chai

I am unable to find a solution to catching a thrown string with Mocha and Chai

**Code being tested:**

```js
function SimpleDate(year, month, day) {
    if (!isValidDate(year, month, day)) {
        throw "invalid date";
    }
}
```

**Test code:**

```js
it("returns 'invalid date' for year = 2023, month = 13, day = 55", function () {
    let actual = new DateUtils.SimpleDate(2013, 13, 55);
    //let expected ='invalid date';
    let expected = expect(() => DateUtils.SimpleDate(2013, 13, 55)).to.throw('invalid date');


    assert.equal(actual, expected);
});
```

I expect the test to pass, but the code I have tried fails saying 'Error: the string "invalid date" was thrown, throw an Error :)'

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the solution is to define a wrapper function that calls the function you are testing, and then pass the wrapper to assert.throws

```js
it("returns 'invalid date' for year = 2023, month = 13, day = 55", function () {
    let year = 2013,
        month = 13,
        day = 55;
    let expectedMessage = 'invalid date';
    let wrapper = function () {
        let x = DateUtils.SimpleDate(year, month, day);
    }

    assert.throws(wrapper, expectedMessage);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should throw an error rather than a string

```
function SimpleDate(year, month, day) {
        if (!isValidDate(year, month, day)) {
            throw new Error('invalid date');
        }
}
```

Comment: I had attempted that and just tried again but the error is still not caught be chai

Comment: oh, I think I see what is going on. You have 2 tests in one section. You have a throw test. let expected = expect(() => DateUtils.SimpleDate(2013, 13, 55)).to.throw('invalid date');
Then you have a assert.equal(actual, expected); test. 
You only need the first one. Try getting rid of 'let expected = ' and the 'assert.equal(actual, expected);'  
The expect should already be testing for the error, and I don't think duplicating it will work. 
Also assert.equal is looking to see if both are shallowly equal. I'm pretty sure that assert.equal is not set up to catch thrown errors.

Comment: And when you throw a statement, you need to catch that error. with a Catch block. You can not store it in a variable